# TSA Wait Times API

Tags: data-request

https://www.dhs.gov/mytsa-api-documentation

There used to be an API for TSA airport wait times, but it seems to have been closed down. Does anyone know if this data is available from anywhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is no good answer to this! Some people have clearly [figured it out](https://www.ifly.com/john-f-kennedy-international-airport/wait-times) but there doesn't appear to be a solid API or easily available dataset.